# <li> tag is created only the first item

Tags: jquery

I do not know what I'm doing wrong but all the items should be within the tag `<li>` item `</li>` but only the first item is, what can be?

javascript:

```
$.getJSON("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20xml%20where%20url%3D'http%3A%2F%2Frss.cnn.com%2Fservices%2Fpodcasting%2Fac360%2Frss.xml'%20AND%20itemPath%3D%22%2F%2Fchannel%22&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=?", function (data) {

    var titles = data.query.results.channel.item.map(function(item) {
    return item.title;

    });

    $(".container-list-podcast ul").append('<li>' + titles.join('</li>'));

});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cf5QU/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have no subsequent opening `<li>` tags. You probably meant:

```
$(".container-list-podcast ul").append('<li>' + titles.join('</li><li>') + '</li>');
// This opens the first item (only) ----^                    ^    ^         ^
// This closes each item except the last --------------------+    |         |
// This opens the second one onward ------------------------------+         |
// This closes the last one ------------------------------------------------+
```

Or if you want to rely on the fact that closing `</li>` tags are [optional](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#optional-tags), it could be:

```
$(".container-list-podcast ul").append('<li>' + titles.join('<li>'));
```

Answer (score 4):

This line needs to be:

```
 $(".container-list-podcast ul").append('<li>' + titles.join('<li>'));
```

Edited to match T.J Crowder's suggestion below.

Comment: That leaves an unclosed one. Mind you, no browser will care, and it's even [officially allowed now](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#optional-tags). If you're going to rely on optional tags, though, you may as well just do `'<li>' + titles.join('<li>')`.

Answer (score 0):

Updated code http://jsfiddle.net/m627u/:

```
$.getJSON("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20xml%20where%20url%3D'http%3A%2F%2Frss.cnn.com%2Fservices%2Fpodcasting%2Fac360%2Frss.xml'%20AND%20itemPath%3D%22%2F%2Fchannel%22&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=?", function (data) {

    var titles = data.query.results.channel.item.map(function(item) {
    return '<li>'+item.title+'</li>';

    });
    $(".container-list-podcast ul").append(titles);
});
```

You were putting the collective string into the `<li>`, not each title.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.getJSON("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20xml%20where%20url%3D'http%3A%2F%2Frss.cnn.com%2Fservices%2Fpodcasting%2Fac360%2Frss.xml'%20AND%20itemPath%3D%22%2F%2Fchannel%22&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=?", function (data) {

    var titles = data.query.results.channel.item.map(function(item) {
    return item.title;

    });

    $.each(titles, function(key, value){
        $(".container-list-podcast ul").append('<li>' + value + '</li>');
    });                

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/deepakb/Cf5QU/1/)

```
$.getJSON("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20xml%20where%20url%3D'http%3A%2F%2Frss.cnn.com%2Fservices%2Fpodcasting%2Fac360%2Frss.xml'%20AND%20itemPath%3D%22%2F%2Fchannel%22&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=?", function (data) {

    var titles = data.query.results.channel.item.map(function(item) {
    return item.title;

    });

    $(".container-list-podcast ul").append('<li>' + titles.join('</li><li>'));

});
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the modified code http://jsfiddle.net/Cf5QU/2/ for the solution.

```
 $.getJSON("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20xml%20where%20url%3D'http%3A%2F%2Frss.cnn.com%2Fservices%2Fpodcasting%2Fac360%2Frss.xml'%20AND%20itemPath%3D%22%2F%2Fchannel%22&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=?", function (data) {

    var titles = data.query.results.channel.item.map(function(item) {
    return item.title;

    });

    $(".container-list-podcast ul").html('<li>' + titles.join('</li>' + '<br>' + '<li>'));

});
```

you have to add break line and new li